# "StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header" when reading ObjectInputStream sent from C# client

Tags: c#, java, stream

**Problem**

I'm trying to send a protobuf message from a C# client to this Java Server but I get this exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A290A08 
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A290A08
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I'm a bit at a loss to be honest. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

- **Java server**

```java
    public ControllerThread(Socket s){
    this.s = s; try {

        this.objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        byte size = objectInputStream.readByte();System.out.println("Server: BYTES SIZE:" +     size);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        objectInputStream.readFully(bytes);
        AddressBook adb = AddressBook.parseFrom(bytes);
        System.out.println("Server: Addressbook:" + adb.getPersonCount());

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("Server: BufferedReader oder PrintWriter von ThermoClient konnte nicht erstellt werden");
        e.printStackTrace(); } 
        } }
```

**C# code**

```
public AddressBook InitializeAdressBook()
{
    Person newContact = new Person();

    AddressBook addressBookBuilder = new AddressBook();
    Person john = new Person();
    //john.id=1234;
    john.name="John Doe";
    john.email="jdoe@example.com";
    Person.PhoneNumber nr = new Person.PhoneNumber();
    nr.number="5554321";
    john.phone.Add(nr);
    addressBookBuilder.person.Add(john);
    TextBox.Text += ("Client: Initialisiert? " + addressBookBuilder.ToString()) + "\t" + "\n";
    TextBox.Text += " Erster Person " + addressBookBuilder.person.First().name + "\t" + "\n";

    return addressBookBuilder; 
}
```

**c# OutputStream**

```
    public void SendMessage(Stream ns, byte[] msg)
    {
        byte size = (byte)msg.Length;

        try
        {
            ns.WriteByte(size);
            ns.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            ns.Flush();
            ns.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
        {
            TextBox.Text += "ArgumentNullException : {0}" + ane.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TextBox.Text += ("Unexpected exception : {0}" + e.ToString());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Java's ObjectInputStream is probably good only for java-java communication. For C# to talk to Java, you'll need a platform neutral protocol.

Comment: @Kaiser4you how was the message generated? And how was it written to the socket? One possibility is that you have genuinely corrupted it.

Comment: @MarcGravell it was written as a byte array. could i use ObjectInputStream with c# client?

Comment: "It is written as a byte array" is somewhat ... Vague :) I was hoping you could demonstrate exactly what you wrote onto the stream. In hindsight, @irreputable does make a good point (sorry) - that may be completely incompatible with what you wrote. We need to see what you wrote. **exactly** what you wrote,

Comment: Please post *useful* C# code .. the stuff that *writes the data* to the appropriate output stream in C#. This problem is not related to ProtocolBuffers. See the error message. I am trying to *help* the question by including an *appropriate* title. **The problem [reported] is *not* related to ProtocolBuffers.** Try to send and receive "just an int" to see.

Comment: but sorry you dont answer my question: could i use ObjectInputStream with c# client? because when i use java client it works...ok i edited my first post

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302570/ioexceptioninvalid-stream-header-00010000-while-getting-data-from-c-sharp-ho To get around this, **do not use ObjectInputStream**, but rather a more primitive stream - e.g. a "plain" DataInputStream in Java and the corresponding "plain" binary output stream in C#

Comment: The c# code you post doesn't show how you then get that onto the socket. I'm happy to help (both protobuf and socket-servers are very familiar), but it is impossible to diagnose a mismatch unless you can see both ends of the pipe. I'm looking for code that: a: serializes the address-book entry, b: adds the length-prefix header, and c: how the outut of a and b get dropped onto the raw socket.

Comment: @Kaiser4you re "could I use ObjectInputStream with c# client" - that depends n exactly what you wrote :) if the bytes on the wire match what it wants: sure. If not: no. Reader and writer need to be using the same rules.

Comment: @pst thanks and what is the corresponding “plain” binary output stream in c#?

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks Ok I edited my first post, I hope, that’s what you are looking for. Could you say me now if i can use ObjectInputStream in this case?

Comment: @Kaiser4you I am struggly to say "can" vs "can't", but I will say that you *shouldn't need to*. If all you are doing is reading raw bytes, I would advise just using the raw stream API. Then check you got the same bytes that you started with. After that, it should be easy. Also: big problems if the length is more than 255 ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks but why 255? How can i change the serialization so that I could use ObjectInputStream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tldr;** The problem is using `ObjectInputStream (Java)` which *only works* with data generated by `ObjectOutputStream (Java)`. In this case the `StreamCorruptedException` is being generated because the stream is being given *invalid* data that was *not* generated by `ObjectOutputStream (Java)`.

Instead, use `DataInputStream (Java)` to read the data generated by `BinaryWriter (C#)`. Both of these only support "primitive" types. As long as the *correct [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)* is [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue) and *[sign stuffing](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html)* is performed as needed: integers, floats, doubles (but not Decimals), and byte arrays can be safely sent this way.

[`ObjectInputStream (Java)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

> An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects **previously written using an ObjectOutputStream [in Java].**

[`DataInputSteam (Java)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html):

> A data input stream lets an application **read primitive [..] types** from an underlying input stream ..

[`BinaryWriter (C#)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx):

> **Writes primitive types** in binary to a stream and supports writing strings in a specific encoding.

---

Notes:

- [DataInputSteam (Java) is big-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862023/little-endian-datainputstream), but [BinaryWriter (C#) must be converted to big-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540251/binarywriter-endian-issue).
- There are no issues (aside from endianness) when transferring the `char/character`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double` data-types as they have the same signed nature and bitwise representation in C# and Java.
- Signed problems can arise for `byte (Java, signed)` vs `byte (C#, unsigned)`. Thankfully, *ProtocolBuffer will automatically handle this* if given the appropriate `byte[] (Java or C#)`.
- Strings can provide additional fun due to slight encoding differences.

Answer (score 0):

So with this c# OutputStream method and **DataInputStream** ( Java) instead ObjectOutputSteam it works without any problems

```
 public void SendEndianBinaryMsg(Stream ns, byte[] msg)
    {
        byte size = (byte)msg.Length;

        try
        {

            EndianBinaryWriter writer = new EndianBinaryWriter(EndianBitConverter.Big, ns);
            writer.Write(size); 
            writer.Write(msg); 
            writer.Flush();
            ns.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
        {
            TextBox.Text += "ArgumentNullException : {0}" + ane.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TextBox.Text += ("Unexpected exception : {0}" + e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

**Notes:**

I get **EndianBinaryWriter** and **EndianBitConverter** from [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).